# What does a “B” mean on the special hazard area of a safety diamond?

Tags: safety

I was passing by a building and noticed a safety diamond on it. I also saw that the specific hazard area has a “B” symbol. I tried to find information about this and the closest thing I could find was “BIO” indicating a biological hazard, but the diamond says “B”, and is on a manufacturing building. What could this symbol mean? [image: A picture of the side of a building. The building reads “mil3” on the right center in blue, and in the top center there is an NFPA safety diamond. The diamond reads one for health hazard, one for flammability, and zero for reactivity, and in the special hazards there is the capital letter B.]

Comment: That diamond comes from the National Fire Protection Association (NFPA), based  in the US. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFPA_704, the white division is for specific hazards, and that "B" is not part of the NFPA standard. The Wikipedia article mentions that sometimes jurisdictions will use unofficial symbols there, which have specific meaning within that jurisdiction. I think your best bet for getting an answer would be to contact the fire dept. in that jurisdiction and ask them what "B" means (or contact the company directly). Let us know what you find! I'm hoping for "boom".